# How can c++ compiler know where is the class

Tags: c++, compilation

If you defined a class for doing something, all you need to do in order to use it is to include a header file (.h file) that contains its methods prototypes, but you don't have to include the class file itself (the .cpp file which contains the actual implementation of class methods),

Does that mean that the .cpp file must have a name identical to its header file so the compiler matches names to locate the .cpp file?

OR

When the compiler meets a function (method) call it goes to header files and sees if it has a prototype. Then it searches for implementation in its built-in functions, if not found it searches in all .cpp files in the current directory?

Or are both assumptions not true?

Answer (score 4):

Filenames are irrelevant in C++. The *linker* puts all the pieces together. All you need to know while com­pi­ling a bit of C++ code is what the names of things mean. And that's the purpose of *declarations* and *class de­fi­ni­tions*: They introduce names and thus give the compiler enough information to generate code:

**file1.cpp:**

```
int f(int, bool);         // declaration

class Foo;                // class declaration

class Bar { int g(); };   // class definition (implies declaration)

int main()
{
    Foo * p;              // OK, Foo * is a complete type, since we know that
                          // "Foo" denotes a class

    // p->h();            // Error: We don't know what Foo actually is!

    Bar b;                // OK, we know how size and alignment for Bar

    int m = b.g();        // OK, we know what sort of function B::g() is

    int n = f(50, true);  // OK, we don't need to know what f does

    return m + n;
}
```

When the above code is compiled, it will contain *unresolved symbols* for `f` and `B::g`. As long as *one* (and only one) other translation unit contains the *definition* for those symbols, the linker can resolve them and the program can be linked successfully:

**file2.cpp:**

```
int f(int n, bool b) { return b ? n * 2 : 50 - n; }

// include class definition here
int Bar::g() { return f(sizeof(Bar), sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)); }
```

The basic rule is that you can *declare* a function or a class or *define a class* a as many times as you like, but you can only *define* a function and a class member function once. There is one exception: If you declare a function for class member function as `inline`, then you can actually *define* it repeatedly, provided all the definitions are identical.

The corollary of this rule is that you can safely put all the function declarations and class definitions into a header file and include it repeatedly, as long as you only provide the actual definitions once in one single translation unit. (And the `inline` rule allows you to include actual member function definitions inside class definitions – member functions that are defined together with their declaration are implicitly `inline`.)

Comment: I disagree with the statement that "Filenames are irrelevant for C++".  The preprocessor is a part of the language and `#include` most definitely talks in terms of filenames (unless the standard allows this to be implementation-defined, which I doubt).

Comment: @MichaelPrice: Well, yes, and you also have to give the correct filename to the compiler or the compiler won't even run. I'm not saying that filenames are *unnecessary*. I'm just saying that their values are immaterial: If you replace one filename by something else everywhere in your build, it'll still work the same.

Comment: If you `include <iostream>`, the "iostream" is not necessarily a filename. The standard only requires this to create a certain behaviour, not necessarily to actually read a file. That's really pedantic nitpicking though...

Comment: @doomster: That's absolutely correct, and I also never claimed that `iostream` was a filename :-)

Comment: This doesn't explain how the linker finds file2.cpp

Answer (score 2):

The compiler only needs the header file. But all C++ files needs to be compiled, so the linker can produce the final binary.

Answer (score 1):

In order to produce a program, the compiler needs both. Typically, the compilation from C++ to a binary takes place in two steps though, first every CPP file (aka translation unit) is converted to an object file (containing mostly machine code but also an address table). Then, the object files are connected (linked) to each other (for which the address table is needed) forming the final executable. Typically, in a header file, you say "there's a function with these parameters and this return value". In the object file, a call to that function is then recorded as reference to that function. Finally, when linking, this reference is resolved with the actual address of the function that must be provided by other object files.